# fatal: couldn't find remote ref

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to pull changes from a remote branch that I made sure it exists, but when I use source tree to pull from it , this message keeps popping up "fatal: couldn't find remote ref" , how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you added the remote before you pull? List your current remote with `git remote -v`. If it isn't there, you need to `git remote add` first.

Comment: did you found solution ?

Comment: @NirmalGoswami yes, the problem was because my local repo name was not as same as the one on the remote, so I had to make the two repos with the same name

Comment: alright, in mine case, last commit was the case, so committed another change from bitbubucket ui like simply update single line in readme file, later i was able to pull and clone too, before clone was also not working

Answer (score 1):

Start with, in command line under your repository folder:

```
git branch -avv
```

If you see your branch without an associated upstream branch, you can add one:

```
git branch -u myBranch origin/myBranch
```

Then SourceTree should be able to pull it.